# How to extract all video frames using ffmpeg-kit with flutter

Tags: flutter, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert a file to a list of image file. Ideally with an option to extract a frame every X milliseconds.

Do you know if it possible to do so with flutter using ffmpeg?

Been trying with export_video_frame plugin but it is very slow and not stable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Try the below snippet:

```
String command = "-i ${videoFilePath} -r $imagesCount -f image2 ${outputPath}image-%3d.png"
FFmpegKit.execute(command).then((session) async {
        final returnCode = await session.getReturnCode();

        if (ReturnCode.isSuccess(returnCode)) {
          print("Success!!!!");
        } else {
          print("Failed!!!!");
        }
      }
      );
```

Replace `videoFilePath` with the input file path and `outputPath` with the directory path where you want to save the images. Also, the `imagesCount` with how many images you want per frame.

Comment: Thanks! It's working very well. What is the "-f image2" for?

Comment: `-f` represents the output file type, which is an image in this case. Find more about `image2` [here](http://underpop.online.fr/f/ffmpeg/help/image2-1.htm.gz)